Puppeteer app in Docker works in windows but is stuck on Mac M1 chip
I have an app which works on windows, but the same is stuck on Macbook Pro M1.
package.json
{
  "name": "puppeteer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "st": "puppeteer browsers install chrome && nodemon index.js",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "puppeteer": "^22.6.5"
  }
}

Dockerfile
FROM node:20.12.2-bullseye As base

# install chrome dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
    --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# If running Docker >= 1.13.0 use docker run's --init arg to reap zombie processes, otherwise
# uncomment the following lines to have `dumb-init` as PID 1
ADD https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.2/dumb-init_1.2.2_x86_64 /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json /app

RUN npm install

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 5007

CMD ["npm", "run", "st"]

index.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">  <head>    <title></title>   <style type="text/css">      .kw-offer-letter-body {        text-align: justify;        color: #000;        background: #fff;        font-family: 'Aeonik', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;        font-size: 45px;        line-height: 24px;      }    </style>  </head>  <body class="kw-offer-letter-body">    hello this is a pdf file.. </body></html>`

async function generatePdf3(html) {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: 'new',
            args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
        });

        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.setContent(html);

        const data = await page.pdf({ 
            path: 'example5.pdf', 
            format: 'A4', 
            margin: {
                left: '2cm',
                top: '2cm',
                right: '2cm',
                bottom: '2cm'
            } 
        });

        await browser.close();
        return {staus:200, data: "Passed"};
    } catch (error) {
        return error;       
    }
}

app.get('/sign', (req, res, next) => {
    generatePdf3(html).then(val=>{
        res.status(200).send(val);
    })
});

app.listen(5007, () => {
    console.log('server running at 5007');
})

docker build command: docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t puppetcc .
docker run command: docker run -d --rm -p 5007:5007 -v /app/node_modules --name puppetcd puppetcc
In windows, the application is running fine and the code is able to generate the pdf file when http://localhost:5007/sign is called from browser.
but on running the same code with docker, the app is stuck in puppeteer.
Also, when i execute docker run, a warning is shown:
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested but the docker container is started after that..
i tried making the build using docker build --platform linux/arm64/v8 -t puppetcc . but this caused the build process to fail.
configuration of Mac:
Apple M1 Pro
Sonoma 14.2.1
Docker version = 25.0.3
Rosetta 2 installed and enabled on docker

Have you seen this post?

What do you mean by "stuck" exactly? Which line of code does it get "stuck" on? When it's stuck, does the line timeout and throw an error, or just freeze forever? If it does throw, please share the full stack trace. Thanks.

yes, even on adding the platform flag on the docker run command, the execution still gets stucked.

@ggorlen, by stuck i meant that when i call the function generatePdf3(), it is neither creating any pdfs nor giving any errors, the api just times-out.

So it hangs forever on const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ with no Puppeteer error message until the Express request times out? Have you tried running the Puppeteer script without Express, stripping it all the way down to the one line of code to minimize the failure? Puppeteer basically always throws when it can't do something, assuming you haven't set any timeouts to 0 (please don't do that if you are--we want explicit errors so we can diagnose problems).

puppeteer timedout with this error - TimeoutError: Timed out after waiting 30000ms
at /app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/util.js:287:19
at /app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/third_party/rxjs/rxjs.js:3:59978
at f._next (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/third_party/rxjs/rxjs.js:3:11821)
at t.next (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/third_party/rxjs/rxjs.js:3:6459)
at t. (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/third_party/rxjs/rxjs.js:3:71381)

I did a clean re-install of rosetta 2. now it works fine.
